# Creating table with changing number of elements in row

Tags: jsp, jspx

I have to create table which can have in one row one or two elements e.g. in one row can be placed label and field (e.g.textField) or only field. it doesn't have to be a dataTable element, it can be anything which looks like a table.
It should looks like this:
   `

```
_______________________________
|____label____taxtField_______|
|textFieldWhichTakesWholeSpace|
|____label____taxtField_______|
|____label____taxtField_______|`
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing anything, but it sounds like basic HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr><td>label</td><td>textField</td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2">textFieldWhichTakesWholeSpace</td></tr>
   <tr><td>label</td><td>textField</td></tr>
   <tr><td>label</td><td>textField</td></tr>
</table>
```